# Cannot link a page to a slider tab

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm just a beginner on this, I am trying to add a page on the slider tab,but was not successful, 
 slide working perfectly but when i add the AandG.html to the tab its not working hopping that someone can help me on this.

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="mp-slider">
      <div><img src="images/slide-5.png" alt=""><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div><img src="images/slide-4.png" alt=""><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div><img src="images/slide-3.png" alt=""><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div><img src="images/slide-2.png" alt=""><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div><img src="images/slide-1.png" alt=""><a href="#"></a></div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- Content -->
<section id="content">
  <div class="container_24">
    <div class="grid_24 content-border">
      <div class="top-content-box">
        <ul id="mp-pags-cont">
          <li><a href="AandG.html">Admin &amp; General</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sales &amp; Marketing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Food &amp; Beverage</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Rooms </a></li>
```

here are the JS code for this,

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
```

Should i include the whole script here?

Thank you for everyone who's trying to help me out of this box.

Comment: What do you mean not working? Do you have a screenshot of example of JS code?

Comment: Not quite sure what you want here.

Comment: Please, improve your question by providing your js code.

Comment: Hi stevenw00 - I mean nothing is happening when i click the link were I added the link.

Comment: Hi Renan,  below are the js code, should I copy and paste inside the question box,  thank you.. <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code works fine. You can run this example, to see, that it works.

```html
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="mp-slider">
      <div><img src="images/slide-5.png" alt=""><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div><img src="images/slide-4.png" alt=""><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div><img src="images/slide-3.png" alt=""><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div><img src="images/slide-2.png" alt=""><a href="#"></a></div>
      <div><img src="images/slide-1.png" alt=""><a href="#"></a></div>
    </div>

<!-- Content -->
<section id="content">
  <div class="container_24">
    <div class="grid_24 content-border">
      <div class="top-content-box">
        <ul id="mp-pags-cont">
          <li><a href="AandG.html">Admin &amp; General</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sales &amp; Marketing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Food &amp; Beverage</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Rooms </a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Your actual problem has to be somewhere outside the posted code snippet. Are your *sure* that your file `AangG.html` exists? Also check UPPER/lower case in your file name.

Comment: Hi slartida, Im quite sure that AandG.html is correct and its located at thesame folder were the index is located.

Answer (score 0):

may be you should use like this

```
<div class="mp-slider">
      <div><a href="#"><img src="images/slide-5.png" alt=""></a></div>
      <div><a href="#"><img src="images/slide-4.png" alt=""></a></div>
      <div><a href="#"><img src="images/slide-3.png" alt=""></a></div>
      <div><a href="#"><img src="images/slide-2.png" alt=""></a></div>
      <div><a href="#"><img src="images/slide-1.png" alt=""></a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it lost the images slider, and link didn't work as well.